# res.redirect(307, `url`) not sending over data anything on the body to the receiving service

Tags: node.js, express, redirect

Like the title states, I'm having trouble understanding why my `res.redirect` is not redirecting the data originally on its `body` to its referring service.

Backend is now on Node.js, Express.

One thing to note is that the body was working with Postman, but when I made the calls through my client (browser), it didn't work.

The overall scheme looks as so:

SERVER 1

1. "client makes POST request"
2. "backend receives POST request" / , "backend redirects POST request"

SERVER 2

3. "redirected request enters route"
4. "using `bodyParser()` to open data on body"
5. "`req.body`" property is completely empty... :(

Here is my code on Server1:
'Client':

```
// note that `brian` and `google` are route parameters
axios.post(`/apicall/brian/google, {
  urls: ['http://www.facebook.com']
})
.then((resp) => {
  const data = resp.data;
  // etc.
})
```

'Server1':

```
app.route(`/apicall/:user/:domain`)
.post((req, res) => {
  const {user, domain} = req.params;
  // the req.body property is still filled here

  res.redirect(307, `http://127.0.0.1:3000/apicall/${user}/${domain});
});
```

Here is my code on server2:
'Server2':

```
app.route(`/apicall/:user/:domain`)
  .post((req, res) => {
     const {user, domain} = req.params;
     const {urls} = req.body; // NOTHING ON THE BODY HERE. :(

     res.send(...);
  });
```

Thanks!

Comment: Redirects are performed by the browser as GET requests to the location you specify in the redirect. They will not have a body.

Comment: @ExplosionPills that's not correct, a 307 request should preserve the body according to this:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Status/307

Comment: @paqash thanks for clarifying -- are you sure that browsers implement this properly?

Comment: just because 307 as a standard will route with post data, doesnt mean express's implementation will. https://github.com/expressjs/express/blob/master/lib/response.js#L857

Comment: It seems to work as expected using `fetch()` and plain form submissions. Is `req.body` an empty object, or undefined/null? Can you see what's happening in your browser's dev tools?

Comment: @robertklep the body property is an empty object.

Comment: so I've found a solution to my problem, but I still don't fully understand what is going on. What I ended up doing was switching out `axios` for `request`, and made the call with the former. And I ended up sending the data as a `form`, and it ended up working. If anyone can help explain why this would work, I'd greatly appreciate it. :)

Comment: @BrianZhou perhaps you haven't configured `body-parser` in the second server to accept JSON data?